# While exporting to xlsx file, 20 digits number will display 15 digits followed by 5 zeros

Tags: php, phpexcel, xlsx

While exporting to xlsx file, 20 digits number will display 15 digits followed by 5 zeros

Comment: I think you're having a problem with [floating point precision](https://blog.demofox.org/2017/11/21/floating-point-precision/).

Comment: I am using Core PHP and PHPExcel (version 2.1). I have tried this $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(
        PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT
    );

Answer (score 0):

- When you type a number that contains more than 15 digits in a cell,
  Microsoft Excel changes any digits past the fifteenth place to
  zeroes. For example, if you attempt to type a credit card ID number
  in the following format  

  -####-####-#### Excel changes the last digit to a zero.
- Excel follows the IEEE 754 specification on how to store and
  calculate floating-point numbers. Excel therefore stores only 15
  significant digits in a number, and changes digits after the
  fifteenth place to zeroes.
- To work around this behavior, format the cell as text, then type the
  numbers. The cell can then display up to 1,024 characters.
- **More Information**
- This behavior only occurs with numbers that are intended for
  calculation, that is, in cells that are formatted as numbers. In
  cells that are formatted as text, you can type up to 32,767
  characters, of which Excel displays up to 1,024 characters on the
  worksheet.

  Because custom number formats are designed to work primarily with
  numbers, you cannot create a custom number format that stores more
  than 15 digits. For example, you cannot use the following format to
  store a 16-character credit card ID as a number:

  -####-####-#### If you type the number 1111222233334444 in a cell that uses the ####-####-####-#### format, Excel displays

  1111-2222-3333-4440 in the cell. The actual number that you are
  attempting to store is 1,111,222,233,334,444, which is over one
  quadrillion. But because this number is so large, Excel drops the
  last (least significant) digit, and puts a zero in its place.

  If you type the number in the cell that is formatted as text, all the
  characters remain as you type them, because Excel does not attempt to
  store the credit card id as a number, but leaves it as text.

Comment: Actually I am printing a SIM numbers so all digits are equally important. I stored this number as var char in my MySQL db. Using PHPExcel 1.8, I am trying to import in xlsx file. Eg: 12345673021821300000